# SVN warning on ci if no files specified

Tags: svn

Is there a way to make it so that if I call `$ svn ci -m "some message"` it yells at me for not specifying the files I want to check in?

I would be fine with it either just asking me to confirm that I want to check in the whole directory, or just canceling the operation.

Normally I try to be verbose and tell SVN the files I want to check in, but occasionally I forgot and end up checking in more than I wanted to.

Comment: I've got this in my .profile:

alias check='svn diff > out; vi out;'

.. then I always do a 'check' just before the svn commit, so I can verify in advance exactly what it is I'm about to check in.  That's usually enough to keep me from shooting myself in the foot...

Comment: I generally try to do the same but it only takes the one time that you forget to follow your routine to shoot yourself in the foot. It would be nice to have it built in somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before I get to your answer, I want to make sure you understand how Subversion works.

Subversion looks at changes as a *changelist* and not as individual file changes. That's why the entire repository revision is incremented whenever there's a commit and not just individual files.

Many people who are use to version control systems that don't handle changelists do things like this:

```
$ svn commit file1
$ svn commit file2
$ svn commit file3
```

This is bad because it breaks the concept of the change list. If `file1`, `file2`, and `file3` are all related to a single change, they should be committed together.

The standard way of using Subversion it to work on a single change list at a time. You work fixing a bug or adding a feature, commit your changes, then work on the next bug or feature. If you are working on two separate bugs or features at the same time, you should really have two separate checkouts.

Doing it that way would allow you to use `svn commit` to commit your change list as a single unit.

---

That said, there is a way to change that behavior of a Subversion commit if you don't list any files and that is by defining your own `svn` function and an alias to the `svn` command.

For example, in Kornshell, there is no easy way of changing the prompt when you do a `cd` to reflect the directory you're in. To get around this, you create a `_cd` function that changes the directory and the prompt. Then, you alias the `cd` command to your `_cd` function.

In your case, you'll define a `_svn` function that looks at the first parameter and sees whether it is `commit`. If it's not, you can safely execute the actual `svn` command. If the first parameter is `commit`, you can then look to see if there is a second parameter. If there isnt', you can assume you forgot to list files, and exit out. The function would look something like this:

```
function _svn {
  if [[ $1 == "commit" ]] && [[ -z $2 ]]
  then
      echo "You need to specify the exact files to commit"
      exit 2
  else
     \svn $*
  fi
```

Then, you create an alias:

```
alias svn="_svn"
```

Now, executing `svn` won't run the `svn` command (at least directly). Instead, your alias will run the `_svn` function.

By the way, I'm not assuming any parameter handling in my function. (What if you add `-m "this is a test") or`--username bob --password swordfish` to the command?). You'll have to extend the function to handle parameters to the commit command. However, this gives you the general idea how you can change a command's functionality to do things like this.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a bash script to call instead of SVN commit, that does some checking of the parameters

```
#!/bin/bash
# usage: ci -[file1...fileN] [-m message]]
# a wrapper for svn ci with some extra features
#  - If no message is given, will prompt user for message
#  - If no files are given, will show user list of files that
#       will be checked in and ask them to confirm or select files 
#       they want to check in

FILES=""
MESSAGE=""
MESSAGE_FLAG=0

# parse files and message from input
for var in "$@"
do
        if [ $MESSAGE_FLAG -eq 1 ]
        then
            MESSAGE="$var"
            break
        elif [ "$var" = "-m" ] 
        then
            MESSAGE_FLAG=1 # Indicates message is coming next
        else
            FILES="$FILES $var"
        fi
done

# ask for message if not present
if [ "$MESSAGE" = "" ]
then
    echo "Enter a message:"
    read MESSAGE
fi

# Check files have been specified
if [ "$FILES" = "" ]
then
    echo "No files have been specified"
    # call to svn st to print out list of modified files
    svn st
    echo "Do you want to check in all of these files (y/n/q):"
    read override
    if [ "$override" != "y" ]
    then
        if [ "$override" = "q" ]
        then
            exit
        fi
        echo "What files do you want to check in?"
        read FILES
    fi
fi

svn ci $FILES -m "$MESSAGE"
```

I should mention I'm a JavaScript programmer so **I had to dust off the BASH books to get this working, so use with caution**.

I put this file in my PATH and called it ci so instead of calling `svn ci` I'll call `ci`, will also save some keystrokes in the long-haul.